# Is it possible to construct a QuantumCircuit object which only shows the 5 qubits and the classical bit where I store the measurement outcome?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I have a 5-qubit circuit on Qiskit, which applies some unitary. Then I have a second circuit which basically measures whether all the qubits are 1, and it does so through a 5-CNOT on an ancilla qubit, and then measuring the ancilla.

I would like to use this circuit without having to care about the ancilla subspace everytime. Is it possible to construct a QuantumCircuit object which only shows the 5 qubits and the classical bit where I store the measurement outcome?